# AngularJS returning placetext html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing a search script to return a bunch of HTML, but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm trying to use $sce.

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http, $sce) {
$scope.url = 'search.php'; // The url of our search

// The function that will be executed on button click (ng-click="search()")
$scope.search = function() {

    // Create the http post request
    // the data holds the keywords
    // The request is a JSON request.
    $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.result = data;


            $scope.trustedExample = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);


         // Show result from server in our <pre></pre> element
        })


};
```

}
Have I done it incorrectly?

Link to the test site is here: http://elliottcoe.com/search/

Comment: What should we enter in the input box to get that "bunch of HTML"?